# Show that $O=\{x \in \ell_2(\mathbb{N}) : \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j}=0\}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Show that  in $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ the subset $O=\{x \in \ell_2(\mathbb{N}) : \sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j}=0\}$ is closed.

I define $T:\ell_2\mathbb{(N)} \to \mathbb{C}$ as $T(x)=\sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j}$ and then $T^{-1}({0})=O$ and how $\{ 0\}$ is a closed set and $T$ is continuos and bounded because is lineal then $T^{-1}({0})=O$ is closed, but I don't know if this is right if there is another way to do because in the book says as hint that prove that $O^c$ is open using that  if $x\in \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ then $\sum_{j \geq 1} \frac{x_j}{j}$ is convergent.

Comment: Your method is correct and it  is the best.